# How to update Custom look up field to user in Case with Account ownerId which is lookup to user using Apex Trigger

Tags: trigger

```
trigger Example123 on Case (before insert, before update) {

    public List <Account> lstAcc =  new List<Account>();
    public Id accountOwner;
   /* For (Case c : Trigger.new){
        lst.add(c.id);
    }*/
    //system.debug('******' +lst);
     list<case> cc= [select id,AccountId, case.Account.OwnerId, AdditionalCon__c from case where id =: Trigger.new];
     system.debug('******' +cc);

      for(Case cas : cc){
      lstAcc = [Select Id, Ownerid from Account where Id  =: cas.AccountId]; 
      }
     for (Case c: cc){ 
       // system.debug('c.account.Ownerid**********'+c.account.Ownerid);     
         if((Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate ) && Trigger.isBefore ){  //Before Insert       
            //system.debug('c.account.Ownerid**********'+c.account.Ownerid);  
             if(c.AdditionalCon__c ==null ){

                for(Account a : lstAcc ){
                    if(c.AccountId == a.Id){
                    accountOwner = a.OwnerId;
                    }   
                } 

               system.debug('AccountOwner**********'+accountOwner);  
               c.AdditionalCon__c = accountOwner; 
               system.debug('AdditionalCon :' +c.AdditionalCon__c);
           }
       } 
          //lst.add(c);
    }

        //update lst;
}
```

Comment: What about your code is not working? Can you list expected results, actual results, and what if any investigation you have done already.  It will make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your trigger as follows

```
    trigger Example123 on Case (before insert, before update) {   

  Set accountOwnerIdSet = new Set<Id>();

  for(Case caseForVarRecord : Trigger.new){

    if(caseForVarRecord.AccountId != null ){
      accountOwnerIdSet.add(caseForVarRecord.AccountId);
    }        
  }

  map<Id,Account> accountMap =  new List<Account>([Select Id, Ownerid from Account where Id IN accountOwnerIdSet]);

  for (Case c: Trigger.new){ 
    if(c.AdditionalCon__c ==null ){

      c.AdditionalCon__c = accountMap.get(c.AccountId).OwnerId;               
    }
  } 
}
```

Please follow some best pratices in writting trigger and avoid using query inside for loop.

Comment: That code will not compile. `cc` is undefined and `accountMap.get('c.AccountId')` should be `accountMap.get(c.AccountId)`